# How to validate Torrent-Files?

Tags: bittorrent, validation

I am interested in finding out if there is a tool, online application or method of checking for invalid `.torrent` files and fixing them?  I'm specifically interested in tools that validate the `.torrent` file against the [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file) [specification](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification).

Comment: @MagicAndi do you mean the .torrent file itself or the eventual file that you download from the .torrent file?

Comment: The problem is any changes to the torrent will change the hash, which then the tracker will not see any other torrents by that hash.

Comment: Define "invalid"

Comment: @Kez, the actual .torrent file, as opposed to the downloaded file.  I'm interested in tools that can check the validity of the .torrent file against the specification - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file.  I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: @Moab, "invalid" as not meeting the BitTorrent specification.  I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @MrStatic, possibly this means that if you do detect an invalid torrent, if you attempt to repair it, you  willactually need to create a new .torrent file using the URLs in the original file, and to generate a new MD5 for the new .torrent file?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot repair a torrent file without recreating it by having a complete copy of the original file being shared.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem with the client is not knowing how to deal with non-English characters; then nothing is wrong with the torrent.

The torrent is validated via the MD5 checksum relevant to the torrent. There are [varying tools](http://www.thefreecountry.com/utilities/free-md5-sum-tools.shtml) that exist to validate the MD5 checksum external to the torrent client which should meet your needs; provided you know the checksum of course.

Comment: My impression is that hash checking is built into the bittorrent protocol, and there is really no need to double check it, invalid pieces are discarded. I've never gotten an invalid file via torrent. OP What problems do the non-english characters cause?

Comment: @CreeDoroft, the non-English characters cause the Transmission client to reject the .torrent file as invalid.  I'm not too worried about this - it is a known issue with the client.  It just led me to ask if there were more generic tools available to check and fix invalid .torrent files.